# What is the right method to override of a WindowAdapter when a JFrame or a JDialog is hidden?

Tags: java, swing, windowlistener

It seems a stupid trivial question but I am not sure about the answer. I would say windowClosing() method, since the documentation says:

> Invoked when the user attempts to close the window from the window's
>   system menu.

For instance, if the frame/dialog to close is setVisible(false) or HIDE_ON_CLOSE or DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE, is what the documentation says still valid?

Comment: I think I found the solution: windowClosed(). Documentation says: Invoked when a window has been closed as the result of calling dispose on the window.

Comment: If the window is using EXIT_ON_CLOSE, then windowClosed will not be called. Depending on what you want to do will determine which method you could use

Comment: No, it's just HIDE_ON_CLOSE, so I would say windowClosed(), right?

Comment: Actually it's seems that I have to use windowClosing and not windowClosed(). In fact the documentation says that windowClosed() is when you call dipose() and not HIDE_ON_CLOSE... even if they do a similar job

Comment: Best bet, write a test project and see what happens ;). The act of the user closing the window and the program closing the window (because of dispose and setVisible) can produce different events based on the properties of the window

Answer (score 0):

> No, it's just HIDE_ON_CLOSE

How about `componentHidden()` from the `CokmponentListener`? Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a ComponentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html).